# How to unit test nested Actions in a Vue application?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I have a TypeScript-based Vue project with [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) as a test framework. I have Actions in a Module which I am trying to test.

My Actions look like this:

```js
  @Action({})
  saveSomeData (payload: any): Promise<any> {
    const { isActive, id, routes } = payload
    return this.context.dispatch('otherModule/createId', '', { root: true })
        .then((id: string) => {
          payload = { isActive, id, routes, type: 'postRoutes' }
          return this.context.dispatch('submitRoutes', payload)
        })
  }

  @Action({})
  submitRoutes (payload: any): Promise<any> {
    const { isActive, id, routes, type } = payload
    return ActiveService.setActive(id)
        .then(() => this.context.dispatch(type, { id, routes }))
  }
```

Here is how my test looks like:

```js
// Mocking createId in otherModule module to return ID
jest.mock('@/store/modules/otherModule', () => ({
  createId: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([
    {
      id: 'someId'
    }
  ]))
}))

...

describe('Testing save MyModule data', () => {
    let store: any

    beforeEach(() => {
      store = new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
          myModule,
          otherModule
        }
      })
    })

    test('Should call createId and then call submitRoutes if ID is empty', async () => {
      const payload = {
        isActive: true,
        id: '',
        routes: []
      }
      const pld = {
        isActive: true,
        id: 'someId',
        routes: [],
        type: 'postRoutes'
      }

      store.dispatch = jest.fn()
      await store.dispatch('myModule/saveSomeData', payload)
      expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myModule/saveSomeData', payload)
      expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('otherModule/createId') // <-- here I get an error
      expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myModule/submitRoutes', pld)
    })
  })
```

**Problem:** My test fails and I haven't found any way to make it work.

The error:

```js
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: "otherModule/createId"
Received: "myModule/saveSomeData", {"id": "", "isActive": true, "routes": []}

Number of calls: 1
```

**What I've tried**

I've followed the [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/testing.html) documentation together with [Jest](https://jestjs.io/), I also tried different solutions from the internet - unfortunately no luck.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

`store.dispatch = jest.fn()` makes dispatch function a no-op, it isn't expected to call `saveSomeData` and, therefore, dispatch other actions.

This assertion isn't useful because it basically tests the previous line:

```
expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myModule/saveSomeData', payload)
```

`store.dispatch` spy or stub isn't supposed to affect `context.dispatch` in actions because the context is created on store initialization and already uses original `dispatch`. It may be unnecessary to do this because these are actions that should be tested, not Vuex itself.

Actions can be spied on module level with `jest.mock` and `jest.requireActual`, or locally on Vuex module object if necessary. Module spies and mocks should happen on top level. Object spies and mocks should happen prior to store instantiation.

In this case a tested units are `myModule` actions, `ActiveService.setActive` and `otherModule/createId` can be considered different units and should be mocked. If `postRoutes` contains side effects, they can be mocked as well.

```
jest.spyOn(otherModule.actions, 'createId');
jest.spyOn(ActiveService, 'setActive');
store = new Vuex.Store(...)

...

otherModule.actions.createId.mockValue(Promise.resolve('stubbedId'));
ActiveService.setActive.mockValue(Promise.resolve());
await store.dispatch('myModule/saveSomeData', payload)
// assert otherModule.actions.createId call
// assert ActiveService.setActive call
// assert otherModule.actions.postRoutes call
```